# How to ensure within a class, deleting row from one data frame deletes a row in another data frame

Tags: python

My problem is given a class with multiple (lets say 2) data frames, I want to ensure that deleting a row from one data frame will also delete the same row from another data frame. So basically they should always be in sync.

e.g.

```py
class C:
    def __init__(self, df1, df2):
        self.df1 = df1
        self.df2 = df2

del C.df1[0] # -> means C.df2[0] will also be deleted
C.df1 = C.df1[0:10] # slicing also means df2 will be sliced
```

Comment: "How to ensure"... well, by writing code that does it? What does your class look like so far?

Comment: I can write code that does it but I want to make sure that if some rows are removed from one data frame they are also removed from another (probably would need some kind of wrapper) as its not only one piece of code that can modify it. I could show you some code but im not sure how useful it is, its just a class with 2 data frame.

Comment: @AKX Although I get what you mean, and you are right, that's kind of an unwelcoming way to put it, isn't it?

Comment: You can overwrite the __del__ and __getitem__ magic methods to achieve this, although as mentioned before don't use a dataframe for which a relational database has been defined.

Comment: @NiteyaShah thats a good point however im not sure if its good practice to overnight these methods? I was wondering if there was another way that the class could handle it

Comment: Inherit the df class into another child class with new methods? Assuming that you are using pandas for providing df, it is designed to work on data by owning it on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## To answer your question

What you are looking for in general, is something like a *setter*, that is a method on a class which runs some code, whenever a certain attribute is set. In python, there are several ways to write a setter on a class. I suggest you read something like https://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php

However, this would just work for setting the attribute, like

```
instance.df1 = some_df
```

For checking on changes of dataframe columns, you *could*  go with an [Observer Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer/python/example#:%7E:text=Observer%20is%20a%20behavioral%20design,that%20implements%20a%20subscriber%20interface.) and wrap your df-attributes into an observer class. To demonstrate the principle:

```
from typing import Any, Callable, Mapping


class ObservedAttribute:
    def __init__(
        self, value: Mapping, callback: Callable[[Any, Any], None]
    ) -> None:
        self._value = value
        self.callback = callback

    def __getimen__(self, key: Any) -> None:
        return self._value.__getitem__(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key: Any, value: Any) -> None:
        self._value.__setitem__(key, value)
        self.callback(key, value)


class ObservedClass:
    def __init__(self, attr_1: Mapping, attr_2: Mapping) -> None:
        self._attr_1 = ObservedAttribute(attr_1, self.attr_1_observer)
        self.attr_2 = attr_2

    def attr_1_observer(self, key, value):
        self.attr_2.__setitem__(key, value)

    @property
    def attr_1(self):
        return self._attr_1


instance = ObservedClass({"a": 1}, {"a": 2})
instance.attr_1["a"] = "newValue"

print(instance.attr_2["a"])  # "newValue"
```

## To solve your problem

That being said, I strongly reckon that your actual problem is somewhere else. Your idea of keeping two dataframes in sync sounds very much like an anti-pattern. Amongst others, the following problems arise with your approach:

1. Who ensures the dataframes have the same length? This is not covered by your code.
2. What is supposed to happen, if one of the df-attributes is overwritten in total?  How do you want to control this?
3. If you are not sure the dataframes are identical upon construction of your instance, that means, you do not have integrity between df1 and df2, anyway. If in fact you can guarantee they *are* always identical, you actually do not need two copies flying around.

So I suggest you rethink your whole approach.

Comment: thanks for the great explanation, yes I agree with you probably its best to rethink the approach but the observer pattern was what I was looking for.